# Input em listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho que receber input(10 números inteiros) do utilizador e coloca-los numa lista mas não permitir números repetidos de serem inseridos.
Tentei mas o programa se vê que os números são repetidos não insere nenhum numero

```
v = [ ]

for i in range(0,10):
x = int(input("Escreva um numero: "))
for i in v:
    if x == i:
        print("Nao pode escrever esse numero.")
    else:
        v.append(x)
print(v)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `range(0,10)` que tem irá pedir `10` números mas se a pessoa colocar um número repetido, irá acabar por não pedir os números suficientes porque os números repetidos foram descartados.

Melhor é transformar o `for` num `while` que pede números até que tenha a quantidade de elementos pretendidos:

```
v = []
while len(v) < 10:
    x = int(input("Escreva um numero: "))
    if x in v:
        print("Nao pode escrever esse numero.")
    else:
        v.append(x)

print(v)
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/43td52)

Answer (score 1):

O que devemos fazer nesta questão é `proibir` a inserção de qualquer elemento, cujo valor corresponde ao valor de algum outro elemento que `já exista na lista`. Para isso implementei o seguinte código abaixo.

Para utilizarmos este código devemos executa-lo, em seguida digitar a quantidade dos valores que queremos inserir na lista. Em seguida, inserir cada um dos valores. **Observe que caso seja digitado um valor que já exista dentro da lista o aplicativo informará que aquele valor já existe e solicitará outro**. Note que, o aplicativo só prosseguirá com sua execução se você inserir valores diferentes aos que já existem dentro da lista.

```
n = int(input('Digite a quantidade de valores: '))
valores = list()
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    x = int(input(f'Digite o {c}ª valor: '))
    while x in valores:
        print('\033[31mO valor já existe! Digite outro valor!\033[m')
        x = int(input(f'Digite o {c}ª valor: '))
    valores.append(x)

print()
print(f'\033[32mA lista gerada foi: {valores}\033[m')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/wlnnwnud-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Se você achar melhor colocar a lista em ordem crescente você pode usar o seguinte código...

```
n = int(input('Digite a quantidade de valores: '))
valores = list()
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    x = int(input(f'Digite o {c}ª valor: '))
    while x in valores:
        print('\033[31mO valor já existe! Digite outro valor!\033[m')
        x = int(input(f'Digite o {c}ª valor: '))
    valores.append(x)

valores.sort()
print()
print(f'\033[32mA lista gerada foi: {valores}\033[m')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/okjvajef-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.